# PHP 7.2 PDO could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

I am trying to run Laravel project and it outputs PDO exception "could not find driver" I am using MySQL.

I have installed php7.2-mysql and php7.2-pdo and I printed phpinfo() to be sure which php.ini it is using and I edited this file:

```
extension=mysql
extension=pdo
extension=pdo_mysql
```

and it still outputs the exception and phpinfo section PDO drivers says "no value".

I am wondering then how to install and enable this to run laravel with mysql.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16 and nginx and I restarted both nginx and php7.2-fpm services

Comment: Can you show the code where you make the connection

Comment: Did you reboot the server after editing the php.ini file?

Comment: SpacePhoenix: Yes, I did.
Nigel Ren: Laravel framework makes the connection somewhere deep in code and I do not think it happens because of it.

Comment: You need to show the database configuration settings

Comment: Is `extension=mysql` the actual setting in your `php.ini`?

Comment: I do not know why I have not done this before asking this question here but.. I purged php* from my system and installed it again. I have installed common mods, mysql mod and in php.ini I have uncommented only `extension=pdo_mysql`. Works now.